# WPF Zoom in and out with both button and slider

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Is there a way to link (if that is the correct word to use) a button to a slider? I’m trying to create an image viewer which would be able to zoom through an image.  I was able to accomplish this by using a slider which Tick is set as .25,.50 all the way  up to 2 which would be a 25% to 200% image scale. But I would also like to implement a zoom in and out button (just like Microsoft Paint) that when clicked would make the slider arrow move to the next or previous tick (depending if zoom in or out) thus incrementing or decrementing the image scale by 25%. I’m new to WPF so I’m not familiar with all the properties I could use but I read that I could animate it by using Storyboard. Besides using storyboard is there another method of accomplishing what I intend to do. Right now my ZoomIn function is just a dummy and throws an exception since I'm still researching on how to do this. I'm Thanks for your help in advance.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="kazoom.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Zoom Window">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Grid x:Name="GridLoadedImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Grid.LayoutTransform>
                <ScaleTransform ScaleX="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}" ScaleY="{Binding ElementName=slider1, Path=Value}"/>
            </Grid.LayoutTransform>
            <Image Name="loaded" Grid.Column="1" Source="image/Desert.jpg" Stretch="Fill" />
        </Grid>
    </ScrollViewer>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="Import" Width="93" Height="20" Content="Import" Margin="10" />
        <Button x:Name="ZoomIn" Width="93" Height="20" Content="ZoomIn" Margin="10" />
    </StackPanel>

    <Slider Name="slider1"
            Grid.Row="1"
            Maximum="2"
            Minimum=".15"
            IsMoveToPointEnabled="True"
            TickPlacement="BottomRight"
            TickFrequency="2"
            Ticks=".15,.30,.45,.60,.75,1,1.15,1.30,1.45,1.60,1.75,2"
            Width="200"
            Margin="20"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            SelectionStart="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>

</Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace kazoom
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ZoomIn.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(ZoomIn_Click));
        Import.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(Import_Click));

    }

    private void Import_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog image = new OpenFileDialog();
        image.FileName = "Picture";
        image.Filter = "Pictures (*.jpeg)|*.jpg";

        if (image.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            loaded.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(image.FileName));
        }
    }
    private void ZoomIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to enumerate through the slider's `Ticks` collection to find the next tick value that comes before or after the current slider value (depending on whether you are zooming in or out).

```
private void ZoomIn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    slider1.Value = slider1.Ticks.Select(x => (double?) x)
        .FirstOrDefault(x => x > slider1.Value) ?? slider1.Value;
}

private void ZoomOut_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    slider1.Value = slider1.Ticks.Select(x => (double?) x)
        .LastOrDefault(x => x < slider1.Value) ?? slider1.Value;
}
```

This assumes that the values in the `Ticks` collection are stored in ascending order of course. Adding an `OrderBy` method call before each `Select` would guard against the values being in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

I admit, I don't know what the *best* way to solve this is. However, a fairly obvious solution does come to mind: bind the value to an `int` property that is the current tick index, using a converter to map between the slider values and the index, and then have the buttons adjust that `int` property. For example…

The converter:

```
class IndexToSliderValueConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public Slider Slider
    {
        get { return (Slider)GetValue(SliderProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SliderProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "Slider", typeof(Slider), typeof(IndexToSliderValueConverter));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Slider != null && Slider.Ticks != null && Slider.Ticks.Count > 0 && value is int)
        {
            int intValue = (int)value;

            if (intValue >= 0 && intValue < Slider.Ticks.Count)
            {
                return Slider.Ticks[(int)value];
            }

            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value must be valid tick index");
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (Slider != null && Slider.Ticks != null && Slider.Ticks.Count > 0 && value is double)
        {
            double doubleValue = (double)value,
                minDifference = double.MaxValue;
            int index = -1;

            for (int i = 0; i < Slider.Ticks.Count; i++)
            {
                double difference = Math.Abs(doubleValue - Slider.Ticks[i]);

                if (difference < minDifference)
                {
                    index = i;
                    minDifference = difference;
                }
            }

            return index;
        }

        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

The above converter simply uses the index to lookup the tick value, when setting the target. On the reverse direction, it looks for the nearest tick value to the current slider value, and maps the slider value to the index of that tick value (in your case, with `IsSnapToTickEnabled` set to `true`, the slider values should always be exactly equal to the tick values, but this implementation is somewhat more robust than one that assumes that would always be the case).

The catch here is that while the converter needs access to the actual `Slider` object (or at least its `Ticks` collection), I'm not aware of any way to pass the instance of the object in which the converter is being used to the actual conversion methods.

The `ConverterParameter` property of a `Binding` isn't a dependency property and so it can't itself be bound. And I can't bind the `Slider` element to the converter in its resource declaration, because even if I name the `Slider`, the generated field's value is still `null` at the time the converter object is created.

So that part of this is a bit of a hack. You'll note that I did implement a dependency property on the converter to take the `Slider` value (in case I ever do figure out a XAML-based way to bind the correct value). For now, I simply set that value in the window's code-behind.

Which, by the way, looks like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SliderIndexValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SliderIndexValue", typeof(int), typeof(MainWindow));

    public int SliderIndexValue
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(SliderIndexValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SliderIndexValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ((IndexToSliderValueConverter)Resources["indexToSliderValueConverter1"]).Slider = slider1;
        SliderIndexValue = 2;
    }

    private void DownButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SliderIndexValue > 0)
        {
            SliderIndexValue--;
        }
    }

    private void UpButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (SliderIndexValue < slider1.Ticks.Count - 1)
        {
            SliderIndexValue++;
        }
    }
}
```

Here, there's a dependency property representing the tick index. In the constructor, I assign the `slider1` object reference to the converter's `Slider` property, by retrieving the object from the resource dictionary and assigning the property directly. Not very elegant, but it gets things hooked up the way I need it.

I also added an assigning to the tick index property just as a sort of "proof of concept". Of course, the fact that it works is also evidence enough. :)

Finally, the XAML for the window:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSO28574624SliderWithUpDownButtons.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSO28574624SliderWithUpDownButtons"
        x:Name="root"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
  <Window.Resources>
    <local:IndexToSliderValueConverter x:Key="indexToSliderValueConverter1"/>
  </Window.Resources>

  <StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <StackPanel.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
          <Setter Property="Margin" Value="3" />
        </Style>
      </StackPanel.Resources>
      <Button Content="Down" Click="DownButton_Click"/>
      <Button Content="Up" Click="UpButton_Click" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Slider x:Name="slider1" Minimum="0.15" Maximum="2" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"
            Ticks="0.15,0.3,0.45,0.6,0.75,1,1.15,1.3,1.45,1.6,1.75,2"
            Value="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=SliderIndexValue, Converter={StaticResource indexToSliderValueConverter1}}"/>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=SliderIndexValue}"/>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Just a couple of buttons to bump the slider up or down, the slider itself, and a `TextBlock` to show the actual tick index property value (again, for the sake of illustration…you obviously don't need that in your own program).

You should be able to use the same technique as above in your own code.

For the record: I have no idea how a `Storyboard`-based implementation would work. It's not clear to me how a `Storyboard` would gain access to the `Ticks` property and an index relative to the current `Slider` value in a way that would be useful in adjusting it. But then, I'm pretty new to WPF myself. Maybe someone else will have some concrete suggestion along those lines.

In the meantime, I know for sure the above works. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution by just simply incrementing and decrementing the slider1 value by .15 and by adding 1.0 it was also able to do zoom 100%. Both button and slider work accordingly with this solution since each push of zoom button also moves the slider which is the effect im looking for. Below is the code:

```
 private void GenericZoomHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (sender.Equals(ZoomOut))   //if sender is ZoomOut object
        {
            slider1.Value -= .15;     //decrement by 15%
        }
        else if (sender.Equals(ZoomIn))   //if sender is ZoomIn object
        {
            slider1.Value += .15;    //increment by 15%
        }
        else if (sender.Equals(Zoom100))   //if sender is Zoom100 object
        {
            slider1.Value = 1.0;        //return to original size of image     (100%)
        }

    }
```